# Como saber um HTTP_HOST e redirecionar para outro

Tags: php, html, http

Ou seja, quando o HTTP_HOST for igual a site1.com ou site02.com
ele redireciona para novosite.com

**Tentei algo como isso abaixo. mas não funcionou.**

```html
<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'site1.com, site02.com'): ?>
  TESTE
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) fica assim:

```html
<?php 
  $domains = ['www.site01.com','www.site02.com'];

  if ( in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],  $domains ) ) {

      // pode adicionar respostas no header depender do que vc precisa

      header('Location: https://www.google.com/');

  } else {

      // faz outra coisa

  } ?>
```

mais uma coisa, use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ou invés de `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` é facilmente manipulável pelo cliente, então a depender do seu proposito pode haver algo inesperado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira é fazer assim:

```
if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ['site1.com', 'site2.com'])){ //verifica se o valor do HTTP_HOST é um dos sites passados
    header('Location: novosite.com');
    die();
}
```